# Projecting the makefile for debug/release configurations

Tags: c++, makefile

Need your help with projecting the makefile. So, what I have and what I want to get. I need to build two executables. Source code is common. Preprocessor macros control differences for both exes, for example, in main.cpp:

```
#if PROJECT_TYPE==FTP
std::cout << "FTP" << std::endl;
#else
std::cout << "SFTP" << std::endl;
#endif
```

Differences aren't only in source code but also in additional libraries that used for linking:

```
FTP_LDFLAGS= -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -s -L $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/Release -l:libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_49.a -l:libcommon.a \
-l:libfile.a -l:libfilesearcher.a -l:libftpclient.a -l:libftplib.a -l:libdbclient.a -l:libsqlite3.a -l:libscheduler.a -l:libws2_32.a
SFTP_LDFLAGS= -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -s -L $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/Release -l:libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_49.a -l:libcommon.a \
-l:libfile.a -l:libfilesearcher.a -l:libdbclient.a -l:libsqlite3.a -l:libscheduler.a -l:libsftpclient.a -l:libws2_32.a -l:libssh.dll
```

Also I want to create debug/release build targets with own CXXFLAGS and output directories, so in result to get following:

```
TARGETS= ftp_auto_backup sftp_auto_backup
```

[Screenshot of dirs tree here.](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/400/ftpprojecttree.jpg)

I want use implicit rule for compiling, smth like this:

```
%.o: %.cpp
$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $(O_DIR)/$@
```

But how can I specify separate O_DIR for each target int $(TARGETS) and for each build configuration? My main problem is in this step. I can paste all the makefile that I have at this moment, but it still won't build anything. Just in case here it is: http://pastebin.com/jjB5Ld1s

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Do you want to build both versions with one call to Make? Or is it enough to be able to build either version?

Comment: @Beta, it will be ok if make will be called separately for each version: make && make debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The simplest seems to be by means of recursive Make. (I am not among those who think that this is always a bad idea.)

```
.PHONY: release
release: VERSION=Release

.PHONY: debug
debug: VERSION=Debug

release debug:
        @$(MAKE) -S ftp_auto_backup sftp_auto_backup VERSION=$(VERSION)
```

Now to make the executables, given `VERSION`. We could handle the two project types with another layer of recursion, but we can do without it (and I won't go into detail about preprocessor macros and compiler/linker flags, since you seem to know about them already-- I'll spell them out if you like):

```
OBJ_LIST = foo.o bar.o baz.o

ftp_auto_backup: PROJECT_TYPE=FTP
ftp_auto_backup: $(addprefix $(VERSION)/ftp_auto_backup/obj/, $(OBJ_LIST))

sftp_auto_backup: PROJECT_TYPE=SFTP
sftp_auto_backup: $(addprefix $(VERSION)/sftp_auto_backup/obj/, $(OBJ_LIST))

ftp_auto_backup sftp_auto_backup:
        @g++ -Wall $^ -o $@ with various flags

$(VERSION)/ftp_auto_backup/obj/%.o: %.cc
        @g++ -Wall -c $< -o $@ with various flags

$(VERSION)/sftp_auto_backup/obj/%.o: %.cc
        @g++ -Wall -c $< -o $@ with various flags
```

Comment: thank u very much!! All works perfect now! I'm very grateful for your help!